# Is there (conjectural) upper bound for the largest solution of Diophantine equation with finitely many solutions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be polynomial with integer coefficients
and $x_i$ integers.

System of Diophantine equations can be brought in this form
via sum of squares.

Assume $F=0$ has finitely many integer solutions.

Let $M$ be the largest solution: $M=\max\{|a| : F(\ldots,a,\ldots)=0\}$.

> Q1 Is there (conjectural) upper bound on $M$ in terms of the coefficients
>   of $F$,$\deg(F)$ and $n$?

Or is it known $M$ can't be bounded this way?

For Thue equations, there is enormous upper bound (probably far from sharp).

If I remember correctly, there was Arxiv paper with many revisions 
giving upper bound in different notation.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from Matiyasevich's result that there is no recursive upper bound?

Comment: @MarkSapir Maybe, but finiteness of solutions is also needed about which I am ignorant.

Comment: I think that you can get a finite number of solutions as well. Basically  the set of values of a polynomial can be any recursively enumerable set, and one can assume that every value is attained at most finite number of times. Then the result should follow.

Comment: I would be surprised if there were such a bound. Otherwise, people would not work so hard to establish effective bounds as opposed to pure existence theorems.

Comment: @MarkSapir “One can assume that every value is attained at most finite number of times”: certainly not without further conditions; for example, this is always false if the recursively enumerable set in question is finite. I would be *extremely* surprised if something like that were known to hold for a wide class of sets. You can assume without loss of generality that every value is attained *infinitely* many times, and since usual proofs of the MRDP theorem proceed by throwing in auxiliary variables all along the way, it’s almost inevitable they end up like that even without asking.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Would you please elaborate? For practical purposes doubly exponential bounds or worse are essentially useless AFAICT.

Comment: @joro: Baker's method usually gives bounds which look completely useless for practical purposes, however, using e.g. continued fractions it is often quite easy to search for solutions up to $10^{500}$, say.

Comment: Explicit bounds for the *number* of solutions are known for many types of diophantine equations for which no effective bounds on the solution *sizes* are known. (In essence one assumes there's a solution in some region which is at least moderately large, and derives both a lower (gap principle) and an upper bound for the coordinates of any larger solution from this assumption, and shows that the lower bound exceeds the upper. One concludes that this region contains at most one solution, but has gained no information how large it may be.) See e.g. surveys by K. Győry, J.-H.Evertse,...

Comment: The question you asked made no mention of "practically useful" bounds- that seems to me to be a different question. Even if there were some theoretical method to always prove the existence of an explicit upper bound, I can't really imagine that it could be both universally applicable and helpful for practical purposes.

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "in terms of the coefficients of $F$, $\deg(F)$ and $n$". If you allow any function of these data, then trivially you can bound $M$ by $M$, since $M$ itself is a function of these data.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.2093.pdf . What I wrote seems to be Matiyasevich's conjecture (probably still open). The double exponent is a conjecture from the paper.

Comment: @MarkSapir Thanks. Is this paper widely believed? The "hypothetical" in title appears weaker than a conjecture.

Comment: @GHfromMO I would accept as answer any explicit function of the coefficients, degree and n. Appears to me different F give might give different functions (if any).

Comment: "Explicit" is a subjective term. Your $M$ depends only on $F$, hence (trivially) it is a function of the coefficients, degree and $n$. If you allow a subjective answer: Falting's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faltings%27s_theorem) is not known effectively, so the (subjective) answer is no.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: It is enough to find one non-recursive set represented by a polynomial with finite preimages. Matiyasevich's conjecture is that it is true. That is very reasonable. For example it is not difficult to construct a Turing machine with that property.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the article:

A. Tyszka, A hypothetical way to compute an upper bound for the heights
of solutions of a Diophantine equation with a finite number of solutions,
Proceedings of the 2015 Federated Conference on Computer Science and
Information Systems (eds. M. Ganzha, L. Maciaszek, M. Paprzycki); Annals
of Computer Science and Information Systems, vol. 5, 709-716, IEEE Computer
Society Press, 2015,

http://dx.doi.org/10.15439/2015F41

Please read the preprint (updated on January 2017):

A. Tyszka, A conjecture which implies that there exists a computable upper
bound for the heights of solutions of a Diophantine equation with a finite
number of solutions,

https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.3826

Let $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=4$, and $f(n+1)=f(n)!$ for every integer $n \geq 2$. We conjecture that
if a system $S \subseteq \{x_i \cdot x_j=x_k, x_i+1=x_k: i,j,k \in \{1,...,n\}\}$ has only
finitely many solutions in positive integers $x_1,...,x_n$, then each such solution
$(x_1,...,x_n)$ satisfies $x_1,...,x_n \leq f(2n)$.

The conjecture implies that there exists an algorithm which takes as input a Diophantine equation,
returns an integer, and this integer is greater than the heights of integer (non-negative integer,
positive integer, rational) solutions, if the solution set is finite.

Comment: I did some formatting, but I wasn't sure whether you wanted $x_i+1=x_k$, or $x_{i+1}=x_k$. Maybe you can fix it if I got it wrong.

Comment: Please read the article, A. Tyszka, A hypothetical upper bound on the heights of the solutions of a Diophantine equation with a finite number of solutions, Open Computer Science 8 (2018), no.1, 109-114, https://dx.doi.org/10.1515/comp-2018-0012

Comment: The Hilbert's $10$th problem is undecidable.